# Change webview width when touching it

Tags: android, view, webview

I have 2 webviews on one layout.
I want that on touch, the touched view will get bigger (wider) on the expense of the other view, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask] to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass WebView:

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView{

    private MyActivity mActivity;

    //Call this on each webview in activity's onCreate after 
        //instantiating the web views. i.e. after setContentView() 
        //and assigning it to a variable with findViewById() or 
        //after programmatically creating the web view.
    public setActivity(MyActivity activity){
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        if (event.getAction()==ACTION_POINTER_DOWN && mActivity!=null){
            mActivity.onWebviewTouched(self);
        }
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

And in your Activity:

```
public void onWebviewTouched(MyWebView webView) {
    if (webView == mWebviewLeft){
        //grow left webview if it isn't already grown, and shrink right webview.
    } else if (webView == mWebviewRight) {
        //grow right webview if it isn't already grown, and shrink left webview.
    }
}
```

Use the Animation class and its subclasses to modify width of the views smoothly. If using a LinearLayout, you could set one view's layout weight to a constant value, and simply animate the layout weight of the other view to get bigger or smaller than that constant value.

If you just want an instant change, just set the view widths directly with LayoutParams.

Comment: current code is m_webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view); when I change it to m_webView = (MyWebView) indViewById(R.id.web_view); I get an exception...

Comment: make sure in your layout you are using the full name of your custom webview class. For example: `<com.myname.mypackage.MyWebView android:id="@+id/web_view" ...etc... />`.